# how to get rid of random back links

Tags: seo, backlinks

When I go into my Webmasters tools and look at the backlinks, I can see some websites that are linking to our site, then when I go onto these websites to see if it is spammy or actually just someone spreading the word about our company I can't seem to find the link anywhere.

For example, there is a website which references our shipping page 39 times but when I go to the pages it says the links are on and look through the source code there is no mention of our website in the links anywhere.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Would it be natural for this other site to link to you? Or is the subject matter completely unrelated and a link to your site wouldn't really make sense?

Comment: Nah they sell 3rd party products (like amazon) but we are not part of them and have no product son their website so no reason for them to link to us or our shipping page

Comment: There are sites that put up links using bugs and other methods just long enough to have a search engine hit the page then removes the links or changes them. As well, sometimes whole pages are created and then changed automatically. This is still fairly common in Russia and Poland and some other countries because local search engines such as Yandex still falls for this trick. As for Google, the effect is near nothing. Somewhere along the line, they will stop. Consider using something to stop scraper bots from hitting your site. ModSecurity may help.

Answer (score -1):

To totaly remove them you can only contact and ask them to.

Comment: This an incorrect answer.  The OP is talking about backlinks ponitng to their site, but your answer describes demoting internal sitelinks from the search results pages.